# How to compute p-value when number of degrees of freedom and chi-square value are known?

Tags: stata

I know how to do this in R: e.g. `pchisq(18.98, df=2, lower.tail=FALSE)`
However, I've no idea about how to write Stata code to solve this problem.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1630882-how-to-compute-p-value-when-the-chi-square-value-and-degree-of-freedom-are-known-in-stata It's always a good idea to tell people about cross-posting.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're interested in more general post-estimation tests check out: `help test`.

Otherwise is seems like `chi2(2,18.98)` or `chi2tail(2,18.98)` are what you're after (depending on what `lower.tail=FALSE` means.

Note that in Stata you'll probably want to put this into a "local" in order to do other things with the output.

For example if you say the following to Stata:

```
local pchi2 = chi2(2,18.98)
display "chi2: `pchi2'"
```

Stata should reply:

```
chi2: .9999243958967154
```

See for more detail and links to the Stata manual section on statistical functions:

- `help chi2`
- `help chi2tail`